# Match a string[] values to enum val, and convert matches to enum[] type

Tags: typescript

I have a string[] where the values I first want to compare to an enum, keep the matches and then convert/create a new var where string[] will become enum[] type instead. Preferably without type assertion (code guideline we have). Maybe with a Array.some function or the like.

Example. Assume I have this enum:

```
enum myEnum {
 apple: 'apple',
 orange: 'orange'
 }
```

I have a string[] with the following values:

```
['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
```

After matching it with the enum, I will have this left:

```
['apple', 'banana'] of type string[]
```

Now, I want to either convert or create a new variable that has the same values, but of type "myEnum" instead.

```
['apple', 'banana'] of type [myEnum]
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [type assertion in TypeScript](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/type-assertion) like so:

```
['apple', 'banana'] as myEnum[];
```

This is an example of the complete function:

```
enum myEnum {
  apple = 'apple',
  orange = 'orange'
}

function getFavoriteFruits(fruits: string[]): myEnum[] {
  return fruits.filter(fruit => fruit in myEnum) as myEnum[];
}

getFavoriteFruits(['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'grapes']);
```